# onDialogClosed listener of onDialogClosed

Tags: android

I have `DialogPreference` dialog instance. How can i register an listener on `onDialogClosed`. I want when `Ok` button is clicked to execute some code.

Is this possible to do with instance of `DialogPreference` ?

I know I can do it like

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    if (positiveResult) {
      String text=MyEditText.getText();
    }
    else {
     // cancel hit
    }
}
```

but i am not extending `DialogPreference`. i have just instance of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preference.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(listener);

Comment: If you're passing an anonymous class like that you must override the methods on the interface.

Comment: you are right thank you. But can i with OnDismissListener check if button ok is pressed?

Comment: onDismiss is fired when i click ok or cancel. Can i catch what i press?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the instance of `DialogPreference`, then you can impement `onPreferenceChangedListener` for the `DialogPreference`.

```
myDialogPreference
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(
                    new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onPreferenceClick(
                                Preference preference) {
                                // Your code here
                    });
```

Comment: can you give me an example please?